# jwysiwyg Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jwysiwyg

im using jwysiwyg and i dont know how to clear the value of the frame to where the user will input the text..

im doing it like this..

```
$('#wysiwyg').val("");
```

but it is not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`setContent` method](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/source/browse/tags/0.7/jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js#217) like this:

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('setContent','');
```

This has the effect of emptying the `<body>` element, so it should do what you're after.